# Display all font file characters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fonts

I'm wondering if there is a way to display all font file characters using HTML/CSS/JS/PHP?

Let's say I would like to display all possible "Arial" characters. Or characters from custom @font-face font.

Answer (score 5):

Fonts can map a wide range of Unicode characters, using codes from 0 to 0x10FFFF. Thus if you really want to see *everything* in any random font, doing it in a loop as has been suggested in other answers is really going to be problematic. Even for the "simple" example of Arial, the lowest mapped character is U+0020 and the highest is U+FB02. Not everything in that range is mapped, however, so if you did that in a loop you'd end up with a lot of empties. Not to mention it would likely be pretty slow.

To do what you want effectively, you're going to need something to crack open the font file, examine the cmap table, and get a list of mapped characters (**not** a range). I'm not sure what your setup is, but you could probably do this server-side with something like [FreeType](http://freetype.org/) or some such.

Comment: Valuable information. Thank you! I just wanted to obtain something like Windows 7 "Character Map" where it displays all possible chars the font comes with.

Comment: Yep. The only way to do that is to look at the font's cmap table (and that's precisely what Character Map does).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you try GD library [**imagettftext()**](http://www.php.net/imagettftext) function.
Example from manual:

```
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The string with character sets
for($i=0; $i<256; $i++){ 
     $text.= chr($i); 
} 

// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: It's a nice feature but I was more interested in printing content (all characters) from font file (like arial.ttf). Your answer will be surely useful, too in some cases.

Comment: In my edit I have included the testing string that has all the characters.

Comment: You would have to generate a new image with ajax if you wanted to change the font with jquery or you would have to have all images pre-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the chr function with a for loop. You will have some characters that don't exist but it is quick and easy. If you want you can be more specific about your start and end ascii value.

```
for($x=1;$x<=255;$x++) {
    echo chr($x) . "&nbsp;"; 
}
```

Then you can just us jquery to change the font face dynamically.

Comment: Thanks! I think that this answers the question, however, I'd like to also skip missing characters. Is there any range for those characters? How can I know what is the number of first and last available character?

Comment: Different fonts have different available characters. I'm not sure how you would skip the blank ones. I'll play around with it and see if I can figure something out.

Comment: Are you looking mainly for 0-9, a-z, and A-Z? Those should be available in all fonts and we can narrow it down to those ranges.

Comment: There's no guarantee that 0-9, a-z and A-Z will be in any random font, particularly an @font-face font which may have been subsetted to reduce the size. The only way to be sure is to examine the specific instance of the font.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, and I resolved it parsing the .svg file. So if you don't have the file in SVG you can convert ttf to SVG and then parse it to get the unicode of the available characters.